# Why can't I comment on my own questions and answers on Stackoverflow?

Tags: bug

This isn't an exact duplicate of anything I could find on meta.  But:

I can't comment on my own posts/answers.  It gives me the box and the submit button, and when I click on the submit button, it acts like it posts, and it refreshes the page, but the comment disappears into the void of nothingness.  There are no error messages or anything.  I just lose my comment

Comment: Browser and version? Anything in the JavaScript console? Posting a comment shouldn't refresh the page. The fact that it is might suggest that JavaScript died and the button is acting like a normal submit button.

Comment: What browser? Tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 12.10
Firefox 18.0.1

Comment: (Huh, looks like I can post comments here.....)  And you're right, no refreshing on meta.

Comment: OK, on page load I get the following error in the console:

Error: Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
Source file: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=32443edd88c1
Line: 13


===

Then, when clicking on the "Comment" link, when it opens the textbox to comment in, I get the following error:

Error: TypeError: d.charCounter is not a function
Source file: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=32443edd88c1
Line: 179

Comment: And you did try clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Yep.  Sure did.  Interestingly, though, I've discovered that if I refresh enough times, I can get 1 out of 13-ish refreshes to let me comment....

Comment: @MrA That's not a great hit rate!

Comment: I dare say it's not....